# DPM 2010 - Performance when backing up Hyper-V Cluster

Tags: hyper-v, cluster, scdpm

At my company we are backing up about 150 Hyper-v VMs in an Hyper-v cluster using CSVs (Windows 2008 R2).

The space used by these VMs is about 18TB on SAN storage and 1GB network.

We are using DPM 2010 to backup the VMs from the Cluster NODEs (6 of them) to our DPM storage SAN. Also using the Software VSS driver rather than the Hardware one and so backing up 6 VMs (1 per node) at a time.

Once the full backup has finished the Express Full typically takes about 14 hours each day to run. i.e. just backing up what has changed during the day.

Does this seems right? Can we speed this up in any way? Would 'Compress on the Wire' help? (I'm not sure how to find out the rate of change but its not going to be much more than 500GB a day)

When the backup is running we are not seems any slowness on anything or any servers working under any real load.

Comment: Same deal here. Extremely slow!

Answer (score 2):

we'll probably need a little more information.  What type of SAN (FC or iSCSI).  What's the link speed of the SAN, and the link speed of your HBA.  How many hyper-v hosts, how are the VM's you want to backup spread across those hosts?  Then we need to know the network speed of your Hyper-v hosts.  Now we need all the same questions answered for the DPM server.  Basically you need to try and see if there is any place where there could be an obvious bottle neck.

Another thing to know, what are the SAN (ie Equallogic, Lefthand, Netapp, emc).  How many drives and what types of drives?  This goes for both the Hyper-V host and the DPM server.

500Gb's of data isn't a whole lot.

Now if you're truly trying to backup 500Gb's of data and it's actually taking 14 hours, that's roughly 82Mbs.  So my question for you would be, do you have a 100Mbs link anywhere in this setup?

500GB * 8 = 4000Gbs.  4000Gbs / 14 Hours = 285Gbs/hr.  285Gbs / 60 = 4.7Gb/min.  4.7Gbm / 60 = .079Gbs.  .079Gbs * 1024 = **81.2Mbs.**

Comment: +1,. And sthat would be GROSS NEGLECT. Because unless hee machiens are from the garbage bin they have 1gbit ether net porsts, the cabling can handle 1gbit and likely the switch can calso handle 1gbit (or is really dead cheap - i mean 1gbit switches cost nearly nothing these days), so someone overlooked that this thing is badly configured and runs 100mbit. OUCH.